# Add an attribute on a condition with angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have a simple dropdown that is populated from an array. 
Users will be editing a record in a form where the priority of the record can be selected from the mentioned dropdown. I'm having difficulty with setting the selected item in that dropdown.
Here's my code for that dropdown:

```
<select *ngIf="formModel" [(ngModel)]="record.priority" formControlName="priority">
    <option value="-1">Select priority</option>
    <option *ngFor="let priority of formModel.priorities"
        [ngValue]="priority"
        [innerHtml]="priority.name"
        [selected]="priority.id == record.priority.id"></option>
</select>
```

The selected priority of the record is however not selected, the resulting HTML shows `selected="true"`.
When I change the code to the following:

```
[selected]="(priority.id == record.priority.id ? '' : null)"
```

The result is `selected=""`, but the option is stil NOT selected.
I have already confirmed that that particular option should be selected.
Also when I change the HTML in Firebug to just `selected` the option is selected.
So my question is: how can I add an attribute on a certain condition so that the attribute is not added to other elements with an empty value?

Comment: Your select `ngModel` must have a value that is in one of your options. Here, your options values are an object, and it's pretty difficult for the HTML to read JS objects. Instead, try using a property, such as `name` or `id`, in your options values, and bind your ngModel to it, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two-way-binding is discouraged in reactive forms. The point is to utilize the form controls instead. Why use reactive form, if you are using two-way-binding? That would mean the model driven form is totally redundant. So if you want to solve this problem using the model-driven form, I'd suggest the following:

Since you are using a separate object (`record.priority`) it cannot automatically be bound as the pre-selected value, you'd have to somehow create a reference. So when building a form you can do this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  priority: [this.formModel.priorities.find(x => x.id == this.record.priority.id)]
});
```

And the template would look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select *ngIf="formModel" formControlName="priority">
    <option value="-1">Select priority</option>
    <option *ngFor="let priority of formModel.priorities"
      [ngValue]="priority"
      [innerHtml]="priority.name"></option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Now the value object you are getting from the form holds this value.

if having the `record` coming async, you can set a boolean flag to not show the form until the values have been set. Or you can build an empty form initially and then use `setValue()` for the form control.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/goBepOasFB4NYMOFk5qI?p=preview)**

EDIT: Looking closer, that you want to have the condition to set `null` if there is no value for `record.priority`? That can be done well in the form control as well:

```
priority: [this.record.priority ? this.formModel.priorities.find(x => x.id == this.record.priority.id) : null]
```

Comment: With that code the correct option is selected indeed.
The problem now is how can i reflect any changes made to `record`?
`record` is actually an `@Input()` of this component.

Comment: `this.record.priority = this.myForm.controls['priority'].value` works, but there must be an easier way I hope.

Comment: Why do you need to add the value to `record`? You have the value in the object created by form, why not use that? :) **OR** Do you actually need the `record` to do some additional things? Maybe reconsider the reactive form and do a template-driven form, because as said, two-way-binding is discouraged. The whole point is to "replace" the two-way-binding with model-driven form. Maybe your requirement is more suitable for a template driven form? Hard to tell based only on this information :)

Comment: From what I am understanding you want to post this form to the backend. You don't need `record` for that? You can just use the form object. Check this modified plunker and console. You have the value corresponding the `record` object: http://plnkr.co/edit/iwlzA5Pi2FcfyXoFCPJZ?p=preview

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<select *ngIf="formModel" [(ngModel)]="record.priority.id" formControlName="priority">
    <option value="-1">Select priority</option>
    <option *ngFor="let priority of formModel.priorities"
        [ngValue]="priority.id"
        [innerHtml]="priority.name"></option>
</select>
```

`[ngValue]="priority.id"` and `[(ngModel)]="record.priority.id"` should point to the same value  , and it will work automatically ,

There is no need to write `[selected]="priority.id == record.priority.id"`

Comment: That does work, but when i post the `record` to the server the changes are not reflected in the posted data, so priority still has the old value. 
Also, this works for this specific attribute, but how would that work any other attribute? How can i add or omit an attribute on a condition?